# back to page with pagination

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

all.
I'm a newbie in React. I created simple application with react v18, and react-router-dom v6.
I created a list with pagination using following code:

```
const [fetchPosts, isPostLoading, postError] = useFetch(async () => {
        const postsResponse = await PostService.getAll(limit, page);
        setPosts(postsResponse.data);
        const itemsCount = postsResponse.headers["x-total-count"]
        setPagesCount(getPagesCount(itemsCount, limit));
    });

    const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);      
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1); 
    const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const startPage = searchParams.get("page");
    if (startPage) {
      setPage(startPage);
    }
    const [pagesCount, setPagesCount] = useState(0);


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts();
    }, [page])
```

With pagination all right. But when I open detail page from list and navigate back to list, I get error "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."
If I remove code

```
 if (startPage) {
      setPage(startPage);
    }
```

then everything works right, but I don't navigate back on page.
How can I get rid of error above and navigate back to specific page?

Comment: You never want to update state inside a your render method. Updating state in react causes a rerender. In this case, your `setPage` us updating the state, which causes a rerender, which calls `setPage` again, which triggers a rerender, which calls `setPage` again, which triggers a rerender, which calls `setPage` again, which triggers a rerender, which calls `setPage` again, which triggers a rerender, which calls `setPage` again, which triggers a rerender, which calls `setPage` again, which triggers a rerender, which calls `setPage` again, which triggers a rerender, which calls `setPage` again,

Comment: What is the purpose of that if-condition? What is the use case?

Comment: I would return to direct page when user click button "Back" from detail page

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `setState`, a **rerender** will be triggered. Since you are calling `setPage` in your rendering code, that will continuous cause [rerenders](https://felixgerschau.com/react-rerender-components/) in an **infinite loop**.

You can take advantage of **`useEffect` to ensure that `setPage` does not get called over and over again**. `useEffect` takes a function and a "dependency array", and the function will only be run if a member of the dependency array is changed. So even though there are still rerenders whenever `setState` is called, `useEffect` knows that it doesn't need to keep calling it over and over.

You could replace the `if (startPage) {setPage(startPage);}` with a line like this:

```
useEffect(() => setPage(startPage),[startPage])
```

The above code says to *only* run `setPage(startPage)` if `startPage` changes.

Looking at your code though, it seems like you are only using `startPage` to set `page`, which may be an unnecessary step.

You already have a useEffect checking for when there's a change to page. You can just put `startPage` in the [dependency array](https://dennyscott.io/use-effect-dependency-array/) to simplify things, and then you can delete the `page`/`setPage` `useState` (and the line of code mentioned above).

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts();
    }, [startPage])
```

The above block says to only run `fetchPosts` if `startPage` changes.

Comment: Ok, I got your solution. Your solution is good to prevent error with infinite rendering loop. But you solution don't give me ability to return on N page of my list from page with detail info.